# Get Associated Pattern String from a CurrencyNegativePattern

Tags: c#, string, globalization, currency, number-formatting

On the msdn documentation of ([CurrencyNegativePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern)) I notice that each number represents a associated pattern string.

There's any way to get this associated pattern string passing the corresponding number?

e.g:

```
<someClass>.GetNegativeAssociatedPattern( 9 ) // returns "-$ n"
<someClass>.GetNegativeAssociatedPattern( 3 ) // returns "$n-"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the table seems to be fixed, you can simply define an array with the patterns in your code:

```
string[] patternStrings = { "($n)", "-$n", "$-n", "$n-", "(n$)", 
                            "-n$", "n-$", "n$-", "-n $", "-$ n",
                            "n $-", "$ n-", "$ -n", "n- $", "($ n)",
                            "(n $)" };    

int GetNegativeAssociatedPattern(int index)
{
    return patternStrings[index];
}
```

Comment: Yes, apparently it is the only way.